# Interconnect multiple databases on the same MySQL server

Tags: mysql, automation

I am looking for a solution that lets me interconnect several databases.
But let me explain it with the exact example:

I have a main domain (front page for public clients) and four sub-domains (development, management, client, ...)  in the clients webhosting.
Each domain has its own database and runs different software (WordPress, dolibarr, sysPass, our own software), but all databases are stored on the same mySQL server.

If a CRUD is made, I want that the other databases also "do" something with that data.
Basically, automation.

For example - a user on development.subdomain.xyz sets a project task to "finished".
When the UPDATE is done to the "development" database, I want an INSERT with parts of that data into the "management" database and an UPDATE towards the "client" database.

I could write up some script that connects to all four databases and does the operations necessary.
But that feels a little hard to maintain if multiple users shall have access to this "logic" system?

I could also use the provided API's and process the data (again in a script form rather than implementing a whole UI).
That feels like adding an unnecessary, extra security concern and again hard to maintain?

If I want to add additional functionality - like sending an Email as well, that would even make it harder for non-coders to interact.

So I found several of these "Low-Code Business Process Management" tools and now I'm at a loss.
Is that what I'm looking for? Can you throw me some tags, keywords or links to guide my search for possible solutions?

I do not even know how to call such a system or search for it - which stops me from progressing.

Thank you for all tips :)

Comment: Have a controlling script to handle who should have access to what, that script connects to mysql with a user that has access to multiple databases, and make the script make those decisions.

You probably aren't leaving this question without writing some code or using some vendor.

Comment: @Jesse 
So you say for such a case, there is no specific solution out there?
How would I execute such script?

Via CRON? 
I have read about events and triggers - can I somehow listen to mySQL events via php, or do I have to scan the database for new entries every time (like a sync)?

Comment: I would look into queues and have a master-controller process the queue and make decisions. Each site can post an event to the queue and the MC can then do business logic. You can have a dedicated queue system RabbitMQ, or you could just store everything in a dedicated set of MySQL tables. The benefit of this is that each site can say "XYZ has happened" but isn't concerned with what the other sites do with the information, it is the MC's job.